# Can't find a class using Class.forName()

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception, urlclassloader

This is my "test-addon"

[image: -]

And I'm trying to load my "main class" using:

```
Class<?> jarClass;
try {
    ClassLoader cls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    jarClass = cls.loadClass("main.Addon");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new InvalidPluginException("\"Addon class\" was not found", e);
}
```

As you can see in the image, the class exists, but it still returns:
[image]

Line 21: `jarClass = cls.loadClass("main.Addon");`

**QUESTION: why does this happen**

Comment: Because there is no class called that on your runtime class path?

Comment: Is the `Addon` class in the `main` package, or in the default package?

Comment: src is the source main is a default package Addon is a normal class

Comment: @AndyTurner what do you mean by "there is no class called that on your runtime class path".

Comment: If a class with that name were on your runtime (as opposed to your compile time) class path, this would work.

Comment: Going to try that. EDIT: no success, still the same thing

Comment: So, the source file `Addon` starts with this package statement: `package main;`? Or is there no package statement at all?

Comment: @Jesper My Addon class: http://pastebin.com/SfQgjQKv

Comment: Solved. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I used the SystemClassLoader, not my own.

A simple fix for this was: `jarClass = Class.forName("main.Addon", true, this);`

Answer (score 2):

The jar or directory that contains `main.Addon` isn't on the classpath.

Try `Addon` (no package specifier).  In Maven-style projects, `src/main` is the root (default) package.

Comment: This is not a Maven-style project, already tried with just "Addon"

Comment: Well, in that case it's clear: The `main/Addon.class` isn't in the classpath at run-time.